# How to get a list of all files processes in WinXP are holding?

Tags: windows

There must be some application for this kind, for I've never needed it until now, and that I do need it I can't find it.

I know of Unlocker, but it cannot give me a list.

---

***Edit:*** A subquestion on ProcessExplorer's list. Which is what I really wanted to know in the first place. Why does Explorer (Windows Explorer) lock some files (refuses to delete, so I have to take Unlocker) which the ProcessExplorer doesn't show ?

I could make this an another question, but what would be the point, except flooding the board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Not sure that it will list all files per process, but you can search for a file name and it will tell you which process has it open.

Edit: Yes, it does. Select *View/Lower Pane View/Handles* to see all the files open for a given process.

Comment: Comment on Edit: Yes, I'm looking at that now. Under File's. I understand it *should* be there, but it isn't. Meanwhile, Explorer refuses to delete them (some .avi and some .chp files - the .chp files are our inhouse solution, but I'm not holding any process open which should be locking them).

Comment: Comment on my comment: Disregard the last comment. Solved it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything.
Just enumerate the process handle table with Win32 api.
C code posted hundreds of times on Google Groups and underground Win32 boards.